# Can i combine the Visual Basic project web site pages in Visual C# project and make them single project?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vs-web-site-project, vs-web-application-project

I have two web projects one from C#.net and another from vb.net. Means while creating project i selected project as Visual Basic & Visual C#. Can i combine the Visual Basic project web site pages in Visual C# project and make them single project?

thanks

Comment: @Samuel Liew: yes. I added visual basic web project files in the Visual C# web site project. But it is showing me errors as Error `It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.`

Comment: You cannot mix in one project.  Apply the *public* keyword where necessary.

Answer (score 0):

The project is set to compile using a specific compiler... c# or vb which do you want... so you have to separate the c# into its own project... and the vb in it own project.  There is one caveat.  You CAN put aspx pages that are C# and vb in the same project if you don't use code behind pages because they are compiled on the fly... just in time... ;-)